# RDP Session Disconnection using Batch Script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am novice to batch scripting and I am wondering how it would be possible to search for rdp session using username and Disconnection using session id based on the first command output with help of some output modifiers or any other logic to select the session id and append it to " tsdiscon" using Batch script

Code :

```
C:\Users\vijay>query session vijay
SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE
>rdp-tcp#7         vijay      20  Active  rdpwd

C:\Users\vijay>tsdiscon 20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
set "name=vijay"
for /f  "tokens=3" %%a in ('qwinsta "%name%"^|findstr /r /b /i ".*rdp"') do (
    tsdiscon %%a
)
```

Comment: Hi npocmaka,i just want to know does the above code change say if "name=vijay.suprajanaidus".If yes can this code be made general irrespective of username i am setting?becoz the above code does not work for "name=vijay.suprajanaidus".Request you assistance

Comment: @Vijay - I've added more precise findstr pattern.Now it should detect if the  rdp session is the current session or it is not.Before it worked only for not the current session.

Comment: @npomaka - Gr8 :) its working for other User now.Not sure what happened earlier.Thanks a ton.