# How do I remove letters from a variable?

Tags: string, variables, batch-file

I have a variable (%ms%) that gives a result of a ping like 0ms, 134ms, 1828ms, ect.

I basically want to remove the "ms" of the end of the variable.

Comment: What's provoking the question? If you are wanting to ping hosts and get information about the results, then use PowerShell (`Test-Connection`)  rather than trying to parse strings in a batch file.

Comment: Have a look at `set /?`, which quite literally lists this exact situation:  *`%PATH:~0,-2%` would extract all but the last 2 characters of the PATH variable.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the last N characters from a variable by using the batch variable substring syntax `%var:~,-n%`, which means "expand *var* from the beginning of the string to the end minus N characters".

```
D:\>echo %ms%
1280ms

D:\>echo %ms:~,-2%
1280
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier way would be:

```
@echo off
set "ms=19ms"
set "ms=%ms:ms=%"
echo %ms%
pause
```

The syntax of this is `set "result=%oldvariable:stringToFind=stringToReplace%"`

For more information about this, look [here](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)

Comment: Just a side comment - you do a disservice to people trying to debug their scripts when you encourage them to suppress all debugging information in the first line of the script.

Comment: @RyanBemrose although you're right about `@echo off` not being usefull when debugging, it is common practice to put it at the top of scripts in answers, so the example gives the normal, expected output without the unnecesary "junk-output". For example, see [the latest answer on a batch-question with batch-script in it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35162954/5022761)